# how to set recipient in Email IOS

Tags: ios, email

this is what i am using for mailing when clicked on

```
- (IBAction)email:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailViewController setSubject:@"Subject Goes Here."];

         [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"Your message goes here." isHTML:NO];

          [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
          [mailViewController release];


          }

          else {

              NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state.");

          }
```

now there was button for mail when i click on it then that view appear for compose mail
so beside button there is one text field called _emailTextField so what i want is when clicked on button that text field should appear in compose mail view like if in textfield there is hell@yahoo.com then in mailview in TO it should be hell@yahoo as recipient

please tell me how to do that?

Comment: How about reading the documentation of [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  NSArray *recipentsArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"xxx@gmail.com", nil];
 [mailViewController setToRecipients:recipentsArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
[mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject: _emailTextField.text,nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mailViewController.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc@xyz.com",nil];
```